# Is there an inexpensive way to get from Rovinj to Pula airport early in the morning in the offseason?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, croatia

I'm flying out of Pula airport (PUY) at 06:00 on Wednesday, November 18, and I'm trying to decide whether to spend the prior evening in Pula itself, or in nearby Rovinj (which would be preferable, as I'm in Rovinj for Monday evening). I'm not willing to pay the 50-60EUR a taxi from Rovinj or shuttle transfer would cost, so whether I spend the second night in Rovinj depends on the availability of an inexpensive morning link to Pula airport.

Is it possible to get from Rovinj to Pula airport early in the morning by public transit? I can find buses from Rovinj to Pula bus station, such as an Autotrans bus arriving in Pula at 05:15, but I wasn't able to find any which continued directly on to the airport.

If there's no public transit to Pula airport early in the morning in the offseason, is an 05:15 arrival at Pula bus station early enough to take a connecting taxi to the airport and make my flight? What if I don't need to check in at the airport (online check-in and no bags)? If not, are there any buses leaving earlier which would arrive early enough?

Comment: The 4:15 bus from Rovinj to Pula only operates Mon, Tue, Fri and Sat (dani 1256), so if you're leaving on a Wednesday, using that bus is not an option anyway.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I wonder how they manage to have 39 connections per week in the one, but only 32 in the other direction...

Comment: @Alexander Sounds like either the first or last service every day in one direction runs only with the driver, eg from the depot

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo good catch, updated to reflect the 05:15-arriving Autotrans bus I also found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off season, there is AFAIK no public transport to or from Pula Airport at all. After all, there are only two flight movements per day: The late evening arrival from Zagreb and the early morning departure to Zagreb.

It might be difficult to find comprehensive bus timetables in Croatia, since the same route is often operated by several companies, but buscroatia.com tries to do so and has an overview of all buses from [Rovinj to Pula on this page](http://www.buscroatia.com/rovinj-pula/).

The first bus on Wednesday 18th is operated by [Autotrans](https://www.autotrans.hr/en-us/home) and arrives in Pula 5:15 (departure Rovinj 4:40). Since Croatia Airlines requires you to check in at least 45 minutes before departure (that is 5:15 if your flight leaves 6:00), you will have no chance to get from the bus station in Pula to the airport in time.

Comment: I suppose it might *technically* be possible to get to the airport in time for departure if I check in online and have no bags, assuming doors close 10 min before departure (I'd have 20 minutes to get through security and to the gate), but I guess I'll probably spend the night in Pula because I don't want to risk missing the flight. Thanks.